# Visual studio project in samba network drive results in IIS express permission denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

I have created a ASP.NET Web Application project. When I click the "IIS express" button in Visual Studio I get the following in the browser:

*Access is denied.*

*Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.*

*Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'H:\mypath'.*

If I move my project to somewhere on C: then everything works as expected.

H: is mapped to a samba share on a Linux host.
I believe that IIS express is expected to run as the current user when started like this, so in that case the samba credentials should not be the problem.

So...how do I solve this problem?

Comment: My understanding is that IIS Express does not support mapped drives.

Comment: I guess I have to clone my project to c: instead then. (Not a big issue except that I need to remember to do manual backups.)